# Fetch IP Address

Tags: asp.net, ip

I want to get ip address of client machine Like I opened website on my machine which is hosted on any server So i need IP address of my machine not hosted server IP.

Comment: it depends on if the "server" is behind a load balancer/proxy/gateway/etc. If so, unless changes are made on one of those devices to pass on the IP, your out of luck. If the "server" is *not* behind one of those, inspect the HTTP host headers. For details how to do that, go to google or search on stack overflow for "get client ip address asp.net".

Comment: Guy comes in. Asks a question. Gets and answer, and leaves without saying thanks. Makes us feel like code whores.

Comment: @Chase, True . But in this case , He really didn't get an answer.

Comment: @sh4nx0r, he specified [tag:asp.net] and asked how to get client IP address. How did he not get his answer?

Comment: @Chase, Because the answer you suggested doesn't return client ip address. What he wants is the "Internal IP Address".

Answer (score 0):

```vb
    ''# VB
    HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR")
```

```cs
    // C#
    HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]
```

This will get the PUBLIC ip address of the **client** computer. It will NOT get the LAN IP (192.168...)

Answer (score 0):

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]
```

use above syntax in C# otherwise you will get error like 
Non-invocable member 'System.Web.HttpRequest.ServerVariables' cannot be used like a method.